# Kepler's description of lunar mountains before telescope

Tags: the-moon, history, solar-eclipse, johannes-kepler

This question [Why is the lunar relief not visible in photographs of solar eclipses?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/57089/why-is-the-lunar-relief-not-visible-in-photographs-of-solar-eclipses)

Reminds me of something that I remember that Johannes Kepler wrote.  When telescopes discovered mountains and craters on the moon, Kepler wrote something about astronomers knowing about lunar mountains and valleys even earlier, before telescopes.

As I remember, Kepler wrote of using a pinhole to project an image of a solar eclipse on a surface, an image which showed that the Moon was not totally spherical but had high points and low points on its surface.

Is my memory correct?  Did Kepler write something like that?

Comment: Maybe. However, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baily%27s_beads says Halley made the first recorded observations. Surely Baily's beads had been noticed earlier, and perhaps some earlier observer had correctly deduced their cause.

Comment: I don't know that the image *showed* high and low points as much as that people can look at the surface features from above and correctly determine what they're seeing.